# time series database design

Tags: sql-server, database, time

I am a beginner in database design, researching ways in which to implement a time-series data.
Basically, I want to design a database that store battery metrics i.e. current, voltage and the time for users. 
The more I think about it, the more I start to confuse myself. Please help me to point in the rieght direction. So far, I come up with the following psuedo-code:

```
   Table: User
    Column 1: UserID( Primary Key )
    Column 2: UserName

    Table: Battery 
    Column 1: BatteryID  ( Primary Key )
    Column 2: ManufactureSerial
    Column 3: ManufactureDate
    Column 4: UserID (Foreign Key )

    Table: BatteryLog
    Column 1: Voltage 
    Column 2: Current 
    Column 3: SOC 
    Column 4: DateTime 
    Column 5: BatteryID (Foreign Key)
```

Now, my question is: what should be the primary key for BatteryLog table? A batterylog can contain millions of Time-Series rows at a specified time internal.
I am using SqlServer relational database now. Is there a optimization design for it?

Thank you for your help in my research!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an autoincremental primary key for `BatteryLog` table:

```
[BatteryLogID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

This will serve the purpose of unique identifier for each record.

Alternatively, you can create a composite primary key on `BatteryID` and `[DateTime]` if they are also unique for each record (which is usually the case for time series)

Comment: I like the approach of composite primary key as it enables queries like: select rows between certain range of time with a particular BatteryID. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an off-the-shelf time-series database which are designed and optimized to efficiently store and analyze timestamped observations.

List of databases for starters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database

Answer (score 0):

The only optimization that I can suggest for the relational database is this:

```
Table: BatteryLog
Column 1: SOC 
Column 2: DateTime 
Column 3: BatteryID (Foreign Key)
Column 4: Voltage00
Column 5: Current00
Column 6: Voltage01
Column 7: Current01
...
Column 124: Voltage59
Column 125: Current59
```

So basically, each row of this table contains current and voltage measurements for one minute. You can cache the data on the device and send it to the database only once in a minute. The disadvantage is that this scheme works only for one resolution (one second in this particular case). It can be tweaked to support variable resolution but it can't support the variable resolution or sparse time-series.

The real time-series databases are easier to deal with and also, they have better performance characteristics.